# Wrap negative index to size of array

Tags: c++

Given an array of length `size` and an index `n` to that array, how can I wrap the index such that it is always within `size-1`? For positive numbers its simply `n % size`, but how to achieve backwards wrap around when `n` is negative?

What I've come up with:

```
int wrap(int size, int n) {
    if (n >= 0)
        return n % size;
    else
        return abs(size + n) % size;
}
```

But this only works for `n <= size`; How to make it work for any `n`?

Expected output:

```
wrap(4, -1) == 3
wrap(4, -2) == 2
wrap(4, -3) == 1
wrap(4, -4) == 0
wrap(4, -5) == 3
wrap(4, -6) == 2
wrap(4, -7) == 1
wrap(5, -8) == 0
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want the modulo operator with floored division.

```
int mod_floor(int a, int n) {
    return ((a % n) + n) % n;
}
```

Comment: The first % is superfluous. `(a+n)%n` works fine if a >= -n.

Comment: @Fabian "It's superfluous when `a >= -n`". Who said `a >= -n`? :/

Comment: Modulo on negative numbers leads to unexpected results. Hence it should Be avoided. Furthermore the first modulo operation has no benefit und should be removed.

Comment: @Fabian In what way does it lead to unexpected results? The result is perfectly well defined. The first modulo operation allows the function to work when `a >= -n`, so it has a benefit and should not be removed.

Comment: Sorry, you are right!